# Time stamp conversion in php

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, timestamp

Something I've been trying to work out for a while now without any success is how to convert time stamps in php and by that I mean take the time stamp and convert it from

```
Posted: 2014-03-13 01:13:10
```

to

```
Posted: 7 days ago
```

Is there a PHP function that can do this? As when I'm pulling JSON data from the Facebook Graph API search obviously it is just a plain time stamp and I want to convert it so it says .... days, or hours or minutes or seconds ago etc...

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) date time library. It does that quite simplistically -- and it is very lightweight.